# how to focus input element when page renders in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```
export const InputComponent = () => {
  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | undefined>();

  useEffect(() => {
    inputRef.current.focus();
  }, [inputRef]);

  return(<input type="text" ref={inputRef})
}
```

whats wrong in my code. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
export const InputComponent = () => {
  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | undefined>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    inputRef.current.focus();
  }, [inputRef]);

  return(<input type="text" ref={inputRef})
}
```

Try using this code .
[check this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-wind-xqxhe?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thanks @Hritik Sharma

Comment: please upvote if you find it helful.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the closing bracket for the `input` tag.

```
return <input type="text" ref={inputRef} />
```